# Using APC with HHVM / Nginx

Tags: nginx, alternative-php-cache, php

I've been using APC for object caching with a PHP / Apache setup for a year or so and it's been working.

Recently I've been playing around with HHVM and Nginx and installed APC. It seems to be working as it looks like DB queries are being cached in memory however when looking at the APC stats it doesn't look like it's working.

You can see the stats here: `http://128.199.50.72/apc.php`

It's a WordPress site and I'm using the APC drop in for WordPress: https://wordpress.org/plugins/apc/

I can provide more details if needed, but I'm quite inexperienced with server config so wasn't sure what extra to provide.

I suppose one other note is that I've been using APC 3.1.13 but the new server is using APC 4.0.2, I'm not sure if that's an issue.

***edit* - I was using an old version of the Cache Information page (I took it from my server using APC 3.1.13) and now I've added the new Cache Info page it is actually saying the cache isn't running.**

*Additional question - How is it I have version 4.0.2 of APC when 3.1.13 is the latest release I can find?*

Comment: I connected to `http://128.199.50.72/apc.php` and saw a cache hit (probably my request) displayed. What makes you think it is not working?

Comment: It doesn't display the memory used. And it says there's only been 1 hit when there's been far more than that whilst I've been testing it (and obviously you hit it too). Compared with http://198.211.123.245/apc.php

Comment: can you setup phpinfo somewhere so we can check?

Comment: http://128.199.50.72/wpse-phpinfo.php

Comment: do you have error log for hhvm ? I'm suspecting it does not like the APC module so it silently fails to load it.

Comment: There are no errors in the HHVM relating to APC. Just some notices related to the APC Information page I posted.